# Android Studio Firebase Notification Device to Device with Topics

Tags: android

Sorry if this post was duplicated, but I could not find an answer in here, so I decided to post a new question.

Is there anyway I can do to easily send a notification from a device to other device in a specific topics with a single button ?

I know I successfully push a notification through firebase notification by its website in https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/project/notification but I want to do it within my own device.

a full method would be very helpful for me.

```
mSendNotificationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sendNotificationToTopic("title","description","latestNews");
    }
});
```

above is the example of my button.

**UPDATE**

After trying some codes, I decided to combine the notification manager with thread that listens to a firebase database, as follows

```
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseNotification = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notification");
    String subscribedTopic = "news";

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDatabaseNotification.child(subscribedTopic ).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if(dataSnapshot != null) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class) != null && dataSnapshot.child("desc").getValue(String.class) != null) {

                            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                                new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                    .setContentTitle(dataSnapshot.child("abc").child("title").getValue(String.class))
                                    .setContentText(dataSnapshot.child("abc").child("desc").getValue(String.class));
                            int mNotificationId = 001;
                            NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                            mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            });
        }
    };
    thread.start();
```

and it works fine, I could subscribe the users by editing the subscribedTopic and listens to that database only even on background.
So, another question is, can this cause something bad later ?

**UPDATE 2**

I found a bug which the ValueEventListener triggered more than once even though the data changed...

**UPDATE 3**
Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest way I can achieve notification with android and the help of firebase database.

add this to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<service android:name="YourNotificationService"></service>
<application>
    <receiver android:name=".BootListener">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

and then make a java class that extends BroadcastReceiver for boot listener

```
public class BootListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, YourNotificationService.class));
    }
}
```

and then make a java class that extends service to run your notification on background

```
public class YourNotificationService extends Service {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent pIntent, int flags, int startId) {
        mDatabase = /*your firebase*/
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                /* your code */
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });

        return super.onStartCommand(pIntent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

and you could combine this with SharedPreference or user information to listen to a specific firebase database.

Answer (score 1):

First, the user has to generate 
`String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` and then store it in firebase database with userId as key or you can subscribe the user to any topic by `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("topic");`

To send notification you have to hit this api https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send with headers "Authorization" your FCM key and Content-Type as "application/json" the request body should be

```
{ 
 "to": "/topics or FCM id",
 "priority": "high",
 "notification": {
    "title": "Your Title",
    "text": "Your Text"
  }
 "data": {
     "customId": "02",
     "badge": 1,
     "sound": "",
    "alert": "Alert"
  }
}
```

or you can Use okHttp which is not recommended method because your FCM key will be exposed and can be misused.

```
public class FcmNotifier {

public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

public static void sendNotification(final String body, final String title) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject();
                dataJson.put("text", body);
                dataJson.put("title", title);
                dataJson.put("priority", "high");
                json.put("notification", dataJson);
                json.put("to", "/topics/topic");
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json.toString());
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .header("Authorization", "key=your FCM key")
                        .url("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
                        .post(body)
                        .build();
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                String finalResponse = response.body().string();
                Log.i("kunwar", finalResponse);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.i("kunwar",e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

}
}
```